# How to get all date between two column date(fromDate and toDate). And that obtained date must be in single row separated by comma

Tags: sql

```
LeaveTypeID   FromDate                  ToDate
1            2020-09-12 00:00:00.000    2020-09-15 00:00:00.000
```

From the above table i need all date between FromDate and ToDate. I am expecting the output like below. And i using sql serve 2019.

```
Date
2020-09-12,2020-09-13,2020-09-14,2020-09-15
```

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, why did you tag `mysql`?

Comment: Best way to do this would be to create a stored function, aka a user-defined function.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

You need a scalar function for that

```
create function dbo.fn_PrintDates(@start date, @end date)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
declare @output nvarchar(max)=convert(varchar,@start,23);
while DateDiff(day,@start,@end) >=0
begin
set @start = dateadd(day,@count,@datestart)
set @output = concat(@output,',',convert(varchar,@start,23);
end
return @output;
end
```

then you use it as follow

```
select dbo.fn_printdates(fromdate,todate)
from tableA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with plain SQL with [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
Like this:

```
with a as (
  select 1 as LeaveTypeID, cast('2020-09-12' as date) as FromDate, cast('2020-09-15' as date) as ToDate
)
, gen(LeaveTypeID, d) as (
  select LeaveTypeID, fromdate as d
  from a
  
  union all
  
  select gen.LeaveTypeID, dateadd(d, 1, gen.d) as d
  from gen
    join a
      on gen.LeaveTypeID = a.LeaveTypeID
        and gen.d < a.todate
)
select
  LeaveTypeID,
  string_agg(format(d, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), ',') within group(order by d asc) as dates
from gen
group by LeaveTypeID

| LeaveTypeID | dates
+ ------------+-------
| 1           | 2020-09-12,2020-09-13,2020-09-14,2020-09-15
```

Comment: How to get month name and year in separate column

Comment: Can please explain the query? @astenx

Comment: @keerthiseelan Month name and year can be shown in separate column by applying `format` function to dates got from recursive query, and then aggregated in the same way. The query itself is recursive CTE, where at first place you put anchor member (to start with), then use `UNION` operator to add recursive data: access to the same subquery (named with `WITH` keyword) and "increment" the data to the next recursion step.

Comment: And also i have needed add another table for to get leavetypeName using LeaveTypeID. Can you help me. I am new to this field.